# tableau dashboard create the new calculation but no result

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I have two dimensions. Revenue and Transaction.

Now, I create a new calculation called "AOV" by creating:  Revenue /Transaction

However, there is no data for AOV.

when i count(AOV) it shows 0.

How to create the calculation and shows the actual AOV values? Thanks a lot
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Calculation field is right.
You need to change the format of AOV to percentage 
see below image

[image]

[image]